# Calculate the sum of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I want to calculate the sum of :
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}3^k\binom{n}{k}$$
the identity of pascal can helps me here? if not I would like to get some hint
thanks!

Comment: Hint: The Binomial Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is half a row of Pascal's triangle. Do you know what the sum of an entire row of Pascal's triangle is?

The second one is the expansion of $(1 + 3)^n$ by using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases it is useful to know that for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$
$$
(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \,a^k\,b^{n-k}
$$
In fact for $b=1$
$$
(a+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \,a^k
$$
This already solves your second sum: choosing $a=3$ you get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \,3^k ~=~ 4^n
$$
Concerning the first sum, choosing $a,b=1$ you get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk ~=~ (1+1)^n ~=~ 2^n
$$
Now let us split the following sum into two parts:
$$
2^{2n} ~=~ \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom {2n}{k} ~=~ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} ~=~ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom {2n}{n-k}
$$
From the equality $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$, it follows
$$
=~ 2\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k} + \binom {2n}{n}
$$
In conclusion,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} ~=~ \frac{2^{2n} - \binom{2n}{n}}{2} ~=~ \frac{4^n - \frac{(2n)!}{2n!}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

For second use $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{0\le k\le n}\binom nk x^k$$

For the first as $\displaystyle\binom nr=\binom n{n-r}$

$$\implies \binom {2n}k=\binom {2n}{2n-k}=\implies 2\binom {2n}k=\binom {2n}{2n-k}+\binom {2n}k$$

Putting $k=0,2,3,\cdots,n-1,n$ and adding them we get

$$2\sum_{0\le r\le n}\binom{2n}k=\sum_{0\le r\le 2n}\binom{2n}k+\binom{2n}n=(1+1)^{2n}+\binom{2n}n $$

Comment: so what is it $x$ here? $3$?

Comment: @OfirAttia, yes. Clearly

Comment: I understood why is $2$ , you wrote $1^{2n}$ as the $2\cdot $ RHS? why?

Comment: @OfirAttia, putting $x=1$ in the hint of the second answer

Comment: I dont understand why you are splitting it?

Comment: @OfirAttia, to utilize Binomial Theorem, $k$ must span from $0,1,2,\cdot,2n-1,2n$ but we require $0\le k\le n$ in the first question

Comment: There is more simple way to explain the splitting? I understood everything till the part you are splitting, after $2^{2n}$ I dont understand it.

Comment: @OfirAttia, if you have meant the $\binom{2n}n$ after $(1+1)^{2n},$ observe that we have two $\binom{2n}n$ as $2n-k=k\implies k=n$ and each $r$ is unique in $\binom nr$ in $(1+x)^n$ so we have one $\binom{2n}n$  extra with $(1+1)^{2n}$